# Dynamic-conditional tooltips with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tooltip

I need to add the tooltip attribute to a  element conditionally. I am trying to add an ID to it, and calling angular.element inside my controller, so I can use element.attr('uib-tooltip', 'test') on it. Doing so adds the tooltip attribute to the element, however, the tooltip won't show when I hover over the element.

HTML

```
<td id="cellTest" ng-click="ctrl.test()">
  {{ parameter.current }}
</td>
```

Javascript

```
vm.test = () => {
    const cellTest = angular.element(document.querySelector('#cellTest'));
    cellTest.attr("uib-tooltip", "test");
  }
```

When I click the element, the function test() gets called in the controller, and it works just fine. The uib-tooltip="test" attribute gets added to the `<td>`. However, the tooltip won't show.

I would like to add that if I add `cellTest.css('color', 'red');` to the test() function, it works just fine. The style gets added. Why won't my tooltips work? :'(

Comment: please provide code for better understanding

Comment: Hi. My code is as above. There is an HTML element, a `<td>` to be more specific. I have and ID attached to it. I want to manipulate it inside my controller in order to add uib-tooltip to it.

Answer (score 0):

As variant

HTML

```
<td id="cellTest" uib-tooltip="test" tooltip-is-open="tooltipIsOpen" ng-click="tooltipIsOpen = !tooltipIsOpen">
  {{ parameter.current }}
</td>
```

Comment: The snippets of code I've presented on my question represent an abstraction of the true code. What I need is a means of adding tooltips to the HTML via controller. I know how to add tooltips directly, but I need to manipulate the element inside the controller in order to add a tooltip to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use 'title' rather than 'uib-tooltip'? Here is a snippet:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.parameter = {current: 'Parameter with title'};
    vm.parameter.notCurrent = 'Parameter without title';
    vm.test = () => {
      const cellTest = angular.element(document.querySelector('#cellTest2'));
      cellTest.attr("title", "Cell 2 Test");
      vm.parameter.notCurrent = 'Parameter, now with title'
    }
  });
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>  
    <h2>Using "title"</h2>
    <div ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Foo</th>
          <th>Bar</th>
          <th>Click below</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Just another cell</td>
          <td id="cellTest1" uib-tooltip="test" title="Cell 1 Test">
            {{ ctrl.parameter.current }}
          </td>
          <td id="cellTest2" ng-click="ctrl.test()">
            {{ ctrl.parameter.notCurrent }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: WOW MAN! That worked! So epic this answer of yours. Thanks a lot. Your work pals must be lucky as hell, having you by their sides.